# Why doesn't emit event fire by socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using socket.io + express.
I want to emit 'start' and 'user_info' event to server from client. But it doesn't work. I wrote like this...

#### server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
var socket = require("socket.io");
var app = express();
var ejs = require("ejs");
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
var redis = require("redis");
var _ = require("underscore");
require("./models/User");

app.get("/",function(req,res){

  res.render("index",{});

});

  
  socket.on("start",function(data){
    console.log("Started");
  });

   socket.on("user_info",function(user_info){
    var self = this;
        var name = user_info.name;
        var password = user_info.password;
    user.name = name;
    user.password = password;
    var data = JSON.stringify({name: name,password: password});
  });



### client.js


$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8080");

  
 

    $("#register-btn").on("click",function(data){
        $("#notice").html("Registerd");
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#confirm-password").val();

        if (name && (password === confirmPassword)){
                    // user_info event is works.
            socket.emit("user_info",{"name": name,"password": password});
                    // I wonder why  start event does not works.
                    socket.emit("start",{"name": "yahoo"});

        }else{
            $("#notice").html("try again");
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know why 'start' event is not being fired. Do you have any idea?

Comment: don't you have some log on the server, socket.io is quite verbose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the connection part of Socket.io

```
// Noticed I removed the var socket = require('....
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

   console.log('Client Connected')       

   socket.on("start",function(data){
      console.log("Started");
   });

   socket.on("user_info",function(user_info){
      var self = this;
      var name = user_info.name;
      var password = user_info.password;
      user.name = name;
      user.password = password;
      var data = JSON.stringify({name: name,password: password});
   });

});
```

You may want to read the docs @ http://socket.io/

Comment: Not relevant to the immediate problem, but `require("./models/User");` doesn't actually do anything. Its value needs either to be assigned to a variable or to have a method called on it.